# Getting values from RecyclerView EditText?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am struck in recyclerView,

[image]

Here the name and balance fields are coming from two different arrays.
What I need is, here each row has an EditText field. I need to access each EditText on each row. And get values from it.. and a total is displayed on the Total textView. Is it possible? I tried a lot. I didn't get it.

i am attaching my classes here.

**MainActivity**

```
public class GroupCollectionFragment extends Fragment {
String[] nameArray = {"Akhil","Mohan","Anoop","Syam","Athul","Anish","Anand","Prasad","Mani","Oommen"
        ,"Akhil","Mohan","Anoop","Syam","Athul","Anish","Anand","Prasad","Mani","Oommen"
        ,"Akhil","Mohan","Anoop","Syam","Athul","Anish","Anand","Prasad","Mani","Oommen"};
String[] balanceArray={"2354","6578","2345","34654","2542","2354","6578","2345","34654","2542"
        ,"2354","6578","2345","34654","2542","2354","6578","2345","34654","2542"
        ,"2354","6578","2345","34654","2542","2354","6578","2345","34654","2542"};
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
List<DataHolder> holderList=new ArrayList<DataHolder>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_collection_layout,container,false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    setItems();
    mAdapter = new Adapter(holderList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return rootview;
}

private void setItems() {

    for(int i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++){
        DataHolder item=new DataHolder();
        item.setDname(nameArray[i]);
        item.setDbalance(balanceArray[i]);
        holderList.add(item);
    }
}
```

}

**DataHolder**

```
public class DataHolder {

String dname,dbalance;
public DataHolder(){
}
public String getDname(){
    return dname;
}
public void setDname(String name){
    this.dname=name;
}
public String getDbalance(){
    return dbalance;
}
public void setDbalance(String balance){
    this.dbalance=balance;
}
```

}

**Adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<DataHolder> mDataSet;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView anameTxtView,abalanceTxtView;
    private EditText adepositEditText;
    public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        anameTxtView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        abalanceTxtView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.balanceTextView);
        adepositEditText=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.depositEditText);
    }
}

public Adapter(List<DataHolder> myData){
    mDataSet=myData;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_main,parent,false);
    ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.anameTxtView.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getDname());
    holder.abalanceTxtView.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getDbalance());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for a callback, which means whenever a number on one of the EditTexts is changed you want the total number change too.
So first of all you need to add an interface,

**OnEditTextChanged Interface**

```
public interface OnEditTextChanged {
    void onTextChanged(int position, String charSeq);
}
```

Then you need too include this in the constructor of the adapter.

**In the Adapter.java**

```
private List<DataHolder> mDataSet;
private OnEditTextChanged onEditTextChanged;

public Adapter(List<DataHolder> myData, OnEditTextChanged onEditTextChanged) {
    mDataSet = myData;
    this.onEditTextChanged = onEditTextChanged;
}
```

In the onBindViewHolder of your Adapter you need to set a listener for text change and tell the fragment using **onEditTextChanged** object.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.anameTxtView.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getDname());
    holder.abalanceTxtView.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getDbalance());

    holder.adepositEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            onEditTextChanged.onTextChanged(position, charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
    });
}
```

Add this array to your GroupCollectionFragment so you can save the values in your fragment and use them whenever you want them.

```
Integer[] enteredNumber = new Integer[1000];
```

change your constructor call in GroupCollectionFragment

```
mAdapter = new Adapter(holderList, new OnEditTextChanged() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(int position, String charSeq) {
            enteredNumber[position] = Integer.valueOf(charSeq);
            updateTotalValue();
        }
    }); 

private void updateTotalValue() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        sum += enteredNumber[i];
    }

    totalValue.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
}
```

Let me know if you want the whole files. I wrote it and built the apk, it works just fine.

Comment: thank you for your time! i wil go through it! :) and also i need that

Comment: @BraveHeart
Would you accept my answer if it is right? :D

Adapter.java
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24221230/

GroupCollectionFragment.java
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24221236/

Comment: I have null exception problems when text is deleted, where should it be checked in case it is empty?

Comment: I changed the initialisation to this.     int[] enteredAmount = new int[1000];  and then.                              enteredAmount[position] = Integer.parseInt(charSeq);
    private void updateTotalValue() {
        int sum = 0;


        //Advanced for loop
        for( int num : enteredAmount) {
            sum = sum+num;
        }

        textViewRemaining.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }

Comment: can i set an error to textInputlayout based on position, because when i tried to set error, it is appearing in last position of edittext

Comment: nice explanation, thks u coleague!

Answer (score 5):

A better approach to performance

```
private List<Integer> getQuantityList() {
    List<Integer> quantities = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems_rv.getChildCount(); i++) {
        quantities.add(Integer.valueOf(((EditText)Objects.requireNonNull(
                Objects.requireNonNull(cartItems_rv.getLayoutManager()).findViewByPosition(i))
                .findViewById(R.id.quantity_et)).getText().toString()));
    }

    return quantities;
}
```

thanks for [Goku's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47827026/5873832), feel free to shape the method for your own app.

Comment: great solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can get value at action done of keyboard. all you need is to set

`android:imeOptions="actionDone"` 
in edit text. and then just use below code

```
 adepositEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        // Do whatever you want here

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;

                });
```

Comment: This would only happen if they tap `done`, and many users may just click a different field, meaning you would miss several changes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextChangedListener` on `EditText` and save input in new `HashMap` with key as a id of order/unique key for row.

```
   adeposit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                int count, int after) {
  }

 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                           int before, int count) {
  // Save value her in HashMap
  }
});
```

At the end get Values from `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified @MeHdi's answer. There is little fault in @MeHdi's answer which will turn into a big issue, When there is a scroll up/down in recyclerview, items position get changed and its values are getting changed or becoming empty. Also I have number of editText in a single row of recyclerview. Thanks to @MeHdi's idea. Screen looks like below[image]

> OnEditTextChanged

```
public interface OnEditTextChanged {
// here component_id is editTextId (findView by Id)
void onTextChanged(int component_id, int position, String charSeq);
}
```

> Declare below in adapter class globally

```
private Context context;
private List<DataModel> dailyLiqdateList;
private OnEditTextChanged onEditTextChanged;
```

> Adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<DataModel> dataList;

private OnEditTextChanged onEditTextChanged;

public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<DataModel> dataList, OnEditTextChanged onEditTextChanged) {
    this.context = mContext;
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.onEditTextChanged = onEditTextChanged;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View myHolder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
    return new MyHolder(myHolder);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

 // This is important method due to which even if you scroll list, editText values will not get changed/empty. This method will maintain its position in recyclerview
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.bind(dataList.get(position), position);

    holder.firstEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            onEditTextChanged.onTextChanged(R.id.item_firstEditText,position, holder.firstEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    holder.secondEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            onEditTextChanged.onTextChanged(R.id.item_secondEditText, position, holder.secondEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    });


}

public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView headerName;
    EditText firstEditText, secondEditText;

    MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        headerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerNameTv);
        firstEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_firstEditText);
        secondEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_secondEditText);;

    }

    public void bind(final DataModel dto, int position) {
        if (dto != null) {
                headerName.setText(dto.getName());
        }
    }
}
}
```

> Your Activity class in which you have recyclerview

```
// declare these values globally
Integer[] firstValues, secondValues;
// Declare textviews for calculating and setting total values
private TextView firstTotalTv, secondTotalTv;

// Initialize editText values array list, same as dataList size.
firstValues= new Integer[dataList.size()];
secondValues= new Integer[dataList.size()];

// setting adapter on recyclerview, write this in onCreate()
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(thisActivity, dataList, new OnEditTextChanged() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(int component_id, int position, String charSeq) {
            if (component_id == R.id.item_firstEditText) {
                if (Utils.isValidStr(charSeq)) {
                    firstValues[position] = Integer.valueOf(charSeq);

                } else {
                    firstValues[position] = null;
                }
                updateTotalValue1(firstValues, firstTotalTv);
            }

            if (component_id == R.id.item_secondEditText) {
                if (Utils.isValidStr(charSeq)) {
                    secondValues[position] = Integer.valueOf(charSeq);
                } else {
                    secondValues[position] = null;
                }
                updateTotalValue1(secondValues, secondTotalTv);
            }                
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


   // Update Method, write outside of onCreate()
   private void updateTotalValue1(Integer[] editTextList, TextView totalTextView) {
    int pSum = 0, c1Sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < editTextList.length; i++) {
        if (editTextList[i] != null)
            pSum += editTextList[i];
        else if (i == 0 && editTextList[i] == null)
            pSum = 0;
    }
    if (pSum > 0)
        totalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(pSum));
    else
        totalTextView.setText("");
}
```

Comment: could you share the Utils class please?

Comment: public static boolean isValidStr(String string) {
        return string != null && !string.trim().isEmpty();
    } , write this method in your Utils class