# Get sum of Recycler view Edittext and update the parent layout (Custom Adapter)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

How can i get access to parent layout from Recycler view adapter. my objective is get the sum of qty in Recycler view and  update the subtotal in parent.

here is my code.

here is the Main Activity

```
public class project_bid extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference mRef;
RecyclerView ItemRecyclerView;
EditText subtotal, tax, grandTotal;
String key;
LinearLayout bid_total_layout;
projectItemAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_bid);

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("projects/1/project_line");

    subtotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.project_bid_subtotal);
    tax = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.project_bid_tax);
    grandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.project_bid_grandTotal);
    bid_total_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.project_bid_total_layout);

    ItemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.projectRecycler);
    ItemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    ItemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<ProjectDetailsLineBuilder> list = new ArrayList<ProjectDetailsLineBuilder>();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ProjectDetailsLineBuilder item = snapshot.getValue(ProjectDetailsLineBuilder.class);
                list.add(item);
            }
            adapter = new projectItemAdapter(list, project_bid.this);
            ItemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
```

In addition i used the above method to get and pass the value to adapter. the for loop will create performance issue, is there any better solution?

Here is my adapter and view holder class.

```
public class projectItemAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<projectItemAdapter.projectBidItems>{
ArrayList<ProjectDetailsLineBuilder> data;
Context context;
LinearLayout totalLayout;

public projectItemAdapter(ArrayList<ProjectDetailsLineBuilder> data, Context context) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}



@Override
public projectBidItems onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.project_bid_line, parent, false);
    View main = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_project_bid, parent, false);
    return new projectBidItems(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(projectBidItems holder, int position) {
    ProjectDetailsLineBuilder item = data.get(position);
    holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
    holder.quantity.setText("Quantity: 20 " + item.getUnit());
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.desc.setText(item.getDescription());
    holder.unitprice.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if(b){

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


public static class projectBidItems extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    EditText qty;
    EditText total, unitprice;
    TextView quantity, desc, title;


    public projectBidItems(View item) {
        super(item);
        mView = item;

        unitprice = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.project_line_unit_price);
        total = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.project_line_total);
        quantity = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.project_line_qty);
        qty = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.project_line_cal_qty);
        title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.project_line_title);
        desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.project_lined_description);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your question is unclear. However, if you are trying to communicate between adapter and Activity then use interface.

Comment: As @Kunu said the question is unclear..But taking a wild guess. You could add a function to the adapter class like `getQtyCount()` which will access the data set and get the value that you want, perform the required calculations(if any) and return the output. You can directly call this function from the place where you are initialising the adapter (the main class) and use the value as input to one of the views in there.

Comment: @Tyson thank you very much. Calling through adapter solved my problem. It has been 2 years i am learning java but still confuse with these stuffs.

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923831/getting-values-from-recyclerview-edittext