# How to get view from RecyclerView at specific adapter position and get values from those views?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have RecyclerView  having an ImageView and a TextView for each row layout.In ViewHolder in RecyclerViewAdapter, I have click listener as

```
 v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     Images i=list.get(getAdapterPosition());
                     i.setFlag(!i.getFlag());
                     list.set(getAdapterPosition(),(i));
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
             });
```

In that click listener I am changing  Boolean flag such that it can show either an item is selected or not.**Depending on it's value**  I want to Traverse entire ArrayList by checking

```
for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++){
                if(images.get(i).getFlag()){

                    // there I want to get view from LayoutManager for that item
                    //but how to get view for that item and get Bitmap form imageview for that item
                    //end of geting view 
                }
            }
```

**Please help to get view at specific adapter position from Recyclerview**   Image to reflect my problem is as follows [image]

Comment: Are You Using Adapter to set ImageView and TextView ?

Comment: Yes Sir! I have used RecyclerViewAdapter.

Comment: try to add clicklistener in adapter

Comment: and you can  get position of click and you will get imge by position  if you pass list of image view  and post your adapter here

Comment: Sir ! to add click listener is not My problem since We want to Visit Views outside of RecyclerView Adapter and depending on the  Boolean value of flag we want to get Views from RecyclerView layout Manager

Comment: accept answer by @Prem is it solved your problem so other can find best solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this use **`recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(int position)`** to get particular row of `recyclerView`

```
View row = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(0);
TextView textView = row.findViewById(R.id.YourTextviwID);
textView.setText("Nilu");
ImageView textView = row.findViewById(R.id.YourImageViewID);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

NOTE :- only item that is display in screen when you scroll recyclerView than item will removed from memory

EDIT :- you can write a public method in `adapter` to get your `arraylist` in your activity where you can check your flag

Comment: Sir !You are great . It is working .But Sir why sometimes it return null view when  we use View row = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(2);

Comment: @MashhoodQadeerBhatti because of recyclerView the recyclerView hold only item that is display in screen when you scroll recyclerView than item will removed from memory

Comment: Sir ! I want your opinion for my work that If I want to get bitmap from All ImageViews  in recyclerView where flag was true at the end will it work or not.

Comment: @MashhoodQadeerBhatti you can write a public method in adapter to get your arraylist in your activity where you can check your flag let me know if any more help required

Comment: I have used a public method and following code to get text of TextViews that  were selected   try{
           for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++){
                if(images.get(i).getFlag()){
                    View row = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.counter);
                    PrintToast("We got "+textView.getText());
                }
            }

        }
      catch (Exception ex){
          PrintToast("Exception of type ex "+ex.getMessage());
      }

Comment: But for Adapter position when it is not 2  As  Sir! Prem  has suggested that it only gives that are in view and other are null.Therefore I think  can we disable RecyclerView to recycle view

Comment: @MashhoodQadeerBhatti didn't get u

Comment: Sir ! I want  recyclerView to stop recycling the views and If it stop to recycle the views then it means it will never give null view So can we get it

Comment: you can not **` recyclerView to stop recycling the views`**

Comment: Then why that method is given   holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

Comment: @MashhoodQadeerBhatti better to use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826949/how-to-get-view-from-recyclerview-at-specific-adapter-position-and-get-values-fr/47827026?noredirect=1#comment82616566_47827026

Comment: Sir Thanks  Thanks Thanks  ....Thanks a lot. You have solved my problem how to get view from RecyclerView at a specific position.

Comment: @MashhoodQadeerBhatti happy to help you

Comment: if you dont want to use a RecyclerView , just use a ListView, it will not recycle the views