# Get EditText Value from RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am trying to get the EditText values from the RecyclerView(Adapter).

```
 class BillingOrderListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView Product, type,vartie,unitnumber, Total;

    LinearLayout CardView;

    BillingOrderListHolder (View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Product = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Product);
        type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        vartie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vartie);
        unitnumber=   itemView.findViewById(R.id.unitnumber);
        rate =   itemView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        Total=   itemView.findViewById(R.id.Total);

        rate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                if (!charSequence.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                    int result = (dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUnitCount() * Integer.valueOf(charSequence.toString()));
                    Total.setText(" = Rs:" + String.valueOf(result));
                    onEditTextChanged.onTextChanged(i, charSequence.toString());
                }
                dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(rate.getText().toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }
```

If the user changes the value in EditText the totall amount gets calculated accordingly. I just want to get the EditText value from the RecyclerView and I generate an Invoice with the total amount.

```
int sNO = 0, qTY = 0, TotalCharges = 0, Price = 0;
    String ProductType, Type, Veriety;

    for (int i = 0; i < DeliverOrderlist.size(); i++){

        sNO = i + 1;

        ProductType = DeliverOrderlist.get(i).getProduct();
        Type = DeliverOrderlist.get(i).getType();
        serilno.addElement(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(sNO)));
        Veriety = DeliverOrderlist.get(i).getVariety();
        qTY = DeliverOrderlist.get(i).getUnitCount();
        qty.addElement(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(qTY)));
        description.addElement(new Paragraph(ProductType + " " + Type + " " + Veriety));
      Price = Integer.parseInt(Billing_InvoiceAdapter.dataList.get(i).getEditTextValue());

        price.addElement(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(Price)));
        int result = qTY * Price;
        amount.addElement(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(result)));

            TotalCharges += result;
    }
```

When I run the above code, it works fine if I do not change the value in EditText. If I change the value in any one of the EditText in recyclerView, it gets the last EditText box value from the recyclerView and sets that value to the EditText value that I edited. I am sorry if I am not clear with the Information. Am I doing anything wrong? Can

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923831/getting-values-from-recyclerview-edittext) but it works only if I edit the value in the EditText. Otherwise it gives null point exception error. anyone help me with this please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to null the listener in first in bindviewholder and add listener like below in your bindviewholder method.

```
billingListHolder.rate.addTextChangedListener(null);

billingListHolder.rate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                if (!charSequence.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                    int result = (dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUnitCount() * Integer.valueOf(charSequence.toString()));
                    Total.setText(" = Rs:" + String.valueOf(result));
                    onEditTextChanged.onTextChanged(i, charSequence.toString());
                }
                dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(rate.getText().toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. No it's not working, if I add the addTextChangedListener in the onBindViewHolder, it  doesn't calculate the unitcount and the integer in the EditText for the first time. It works only if I edit the value in the EditText. It should calculate the total even if I don't make any changes to the value that is already in the EditText. @Deep Naik

Comment: simply write that code outside the onTextChange method and for changing values on text change keep the current code.

Comment: Thank you. Its working. But if I add billingListHolder.rate.addTextChangedListener(null); it crashes the app. Without billingListHolder.rate.addTextChangedListener(null); its working. Thank you @DeepNaik